# Image not resizing to fit CSS

Tags: css, reactjs, image, image-resizing

I'm making a website in React. I have a card, with an image in its background. The problem is, the image which I'm trying to set is not fitting in the card. Either it is too big or too small, plus the clarity is low.

I tried `object-fit: contain` and `max-width: auto` but didn't work. Please do check my code:

```css
.card {
  width: 350px;
  height: 370px;
  border-radius: 15px;
  padding: 1.5rem;
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  align-items: flex-end;
  transition: 0.4s ease-out;
  box-shadow: 0px 7px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}
.card:hover {
  transform: translateY(20px);
}
.card:hover:before {
  opacity: 1;
}
.card:hover .info {
  opacity: 1;
  transform: translateY(0px);
}
.card:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  border-radius: 15px;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
  z-index: 2;
  transition: 0.5s;
  opacity: 0;
}
.card img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  border-radius: 15px;
}
.card .info {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 3;
  color: white;
  opacity: 0;
  transform: translateY(30px);
  transition: 0.5s;
}
.card .info h1 {
  margin: 0px;
  font-size: 2rem;
}
.card .info p {
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  font-size: 15px;
  margin-top: 8px;
}
.card .info button {
  padding: 0.6rem;
  outline: none;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 3px;
  background: white;
  color: black;
  font-weight: bold;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: 0.4s ease;
}
.card .info button:hover {
  background: dodgerblue;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<div class="card">
  <img src="https://i0.wp.com/autonxt.net/wp-content/uploads/2018/01/autocontentexp.com2018-Lincoln-Navigator5-5b1aebecc618f268352b037fb2253a291d670994-1.jpg?resize=2500%2C1500&ssl=1" />
  <div class="info">
    <h1>Road</h1>
    <p>
      Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text from the printing and typeseting industry
    </p>
    <button>Read More</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Please help me fix this, thank you!

Comment: i ran the code snippet and it seems the image is fitting the card

Comment: No, I want the complete image to fit, not the zoomed one. @abolfazlshamsollahi

Answer (score 0):

use `object-fit : fill`. by the way your image size differs from the size you set on `card` so the image will be streched.